# man command showing: nothing appropriate

Tags: command-line, 18.04, manpage

When I type the command `man -k which`
the console display `which: nothing appropriate.`

I using Ubuntu 18.04.3

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `man which` also does not return any results?
On my Ubuntu 18.04 installation, the output of `man -k which | wc -l` shows that there are 33 occurrences.

Maybe you forgot to install relevant packages/man pages (for example, `/usr/share/man/man1/which.1.gz` is part of package `debianutils`)?
If the above file is found, check the value of environment variable `MANPATH` (and maybe unset it).